# Picture as "numbering" for section?

Tags: graphics, sectioning, numbering, itemize

is there a chance to use a small picture (like 60x25 px) as "numbering" for  sections (or maybe as a item-marker in the item-environment?)
An example of a picture is this one 
[image].

Edit:
I think one could use a itemize list for it, but I would like to customize the section "markers" to this picture. The same picture for each section.
I don't need the number of the sections. I just want the picture to be on the left margin to indicate the beginning of a new section. 
Like a customization for \section*{New Topic}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. This is possible, but how does the picture change if the section number changes? (One thing to consider: A picture can't enter the bookmarks section of a pdf file, however). Changing `\thesection` is no good idea!

Comment: Sure. That's easy.

Comment: In my case it's no necessary to use a toc, the picture doesn't need to change and the sections are more like a list of items.

Comment: @MichaelSchmid: A pure `itemize` list?

Comment: Please see my edited question.

Comment: You should take a look t the documentation of `titlesec`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick and dirty method for `\section` and all other section commands below that level is to redefine `\@seccntformat` to ignore the usual `\csname the#1\endcsname` and insert another command in there, which should be robust, however.

This could be basically anything, in the example I showed a quick `tikz` shaded ball, but an image can be included and scaled accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\picturetodisplay}{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{ente}}

% Redefine it 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\picturetodisplay}{\begin{tikzpicture}\shade[ball color=blue] circle (1ex);\end{tikzpicture}}


\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\picturetodisplay\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A nice section}

\section{Another nice section}

\section{Yet another nice section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Shifting the 'section number' to the margin:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\unquad}{\hskip-1em\relax}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\picturetodisplay}{\begin{tikzpicture}\shade[ball color=blue] circle (1ex);\end{tikzpicture}}


\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\unquad\unquad\picturetodisplay\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A nice section}

\section{Another nice section}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\picturetodisplay}{\includegraphics[scale=0.03]{ente}}

\section{Yet another nice section}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This way sections look like `itemize` lists

Comment: And then I have to replace the text in the second {} of the redefinition to something like "/path/to/the/picture.jpg" ?

Comment: @MichaelSchmid: If you mean `\includegraphics`: Yes! The usual call is `\includegraphics[some options]{path/to/the/picture.jpg]`, The options might be scaling, height, rotating even, if needed, but I don't recommend that in the section heading line

Comment: Thank you very much!
Do you have a idea how to make the text of the sections start at the beginning of the \textwidth-area?
So the picture (section-marker) is in the left margin.

Comment: @MichaelSchmid: That's changing the question ;-)

Comment: Sorry :) It's pretty difficult to specify what one wants to do over text. And there is no picture.

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much.
Can I change where the section-text starts? In my example the section is a few pt off to the right, compared to the line the "boby" of the section is arranged to.

Comment: @MichaelSchmid: I will take a look.